# error of 'package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart' only if I use scrollController on a CupertinoPicker

Tags: flutter

I have a simple pageview() with two pages. the page 1 have a CupertinoPicker.

If I `launch the app -> open page1 -> use the CupertinoPicker` it's OK.

But if I `launch the app -> open page 1 -> open page 2 -> return page 1 -> use CupertinoPicker` I have an error only if I add `scrollController: scrollController,`

If I remove `scrollController: scrollController,` I can use CupertinoPicker in all cases but I loose the controller ... I prefer let scrollController.

```
FixedExtentScrollController? scrollController;


scrollController =FixedExtentScrollController(initialItem: 0);



pageView(
   children[

 //----------------page 1-------------------

 CupertinoPicker(
  scrollController: scrollController,
  ),

    //----------------page 2-------------------

 Container(),

  ]
)
```

---

```
======== Exception caught by foundation library ====================================================
The following assertion was thrown while dispatching notifications for FixedExtentScrollController:
'package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart': Failed assertion: line 2708 pos 12: '!_debugDisposed': is not true.


Either the assertion indicates an error in the framework itself, or we should provide substantially more information in this error message to help you determine and fix the underlying cause.
In either case, please report this assertion by filing a bug on GitHub:
  https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/new?template=2_bug.md

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
#2      RenderObject.markNeedsSemanticsUpdate (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2708:12)
#3      _RenderCupertinoPickerSemantics._handleScrollUpdate (package:flutter/src/cupertino/picker.dart:473:5)
#4      ChangeNotifier.notifyListeners (package:flutter/src/foundation/change_notifier.dart:308:24)
#5      ChangeNotifier.notifyListeners (package:flutter/src/foundation/change_notifier.dart:308:24)
#6      ScrollPosition.notifyListeners (package:flutter/src/widgets/scroll_position.dart:969:11)
#7      ScrollPosition.setPixels (package:flutter/src/widgets/scroll_position.dart:278:9)
#8      ScrollPositionWithSingleContext.setPixels (package:flutter/src/widgets/scroll_position_with_single_context.dart:82:18)
#9      BallisticScrollActivity.applyMoveTo (package:flutter/src/widgets/scroll_activity.dart:566:21)
#10     BallisticScrollActivity._tick (package:flutter/src/widgets/scroll_activity.dart:553:10)
#11     AnimationLocalListenersMixin.notifyListeners (package:flutter/src/animation/listener_helpers.dart:155:19)
#12     AnimationController._tick (package:flutter/src/animation/animation_controller.dart:830:5)
#13     Ticker._tick (package:flutter/src/scheduler/ticker.dart:238:12)
#14     SchedulerBinding._invokeFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1144:15)
#15     SchedulerBinding.handleBeginFrame.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1057:11)
#16     _LinkedHashMapMixin.forEach (dart:collection-patch/compact_hash.dart:539:8)
#17     SchedulerBinding.handleBeginFrame (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1055:17)
#18     SchedulerBinding._handleBeginFrame (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:974:5)
#22     _invoke1 (dart:ui/hooks.dart:170:10)
#23     PlatformDispatcher._beginFrame (dart:ui/platform_dispatcher.dart:286:5)
#24     _beginFrame (dart:ui/hooks.dart:104:31)
(elided 5 frames from class _AssertionError and dart:async)
The FixedExtentScrollController sending notification was: FixedExtentScrollController#6b302(one client, offset 665.7)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have meet same issue at flutter 3.3.8.
It's a flutter framework bug.

`_RenderCupertinoPickerSemantics` was forgetting to unsubscribe from ScrollController events upon dispose.

**upgrade flutter version** to solution it.

reference:

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/110731

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/pull/111977